# Make links in both underlying and overlying divs clickable

Tags: jquery, html, css

In a panel I have a link.

At the bottom right corner of this panel I have an overlay element which take over the whole div when hovered.

In this overlying element, I have a link.

My problem is that the link in the overlying element is not clickable.

Here is my code :

```css
.panel-default1 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.amg-corner-button_wrap {
  display: block;
  background-color: #e8c63d;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  right: -320px;
  bottom: -320px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.amg-corner-button_wrap:hover {
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(4);
}

.overlay-content {
  pointer-events: none;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #333;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 8px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.overlay-content h2 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 0 0 12px;
}

.amg-corner-button_wrap:hover~.overlay-content {
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default1">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <div class='amg-corner-button_wrap'></div>

    <div class="overlay-content">
      <h2>Image Ink Logo</h2>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- panel body -->

</div>
<!-- panel default -->
```

I believe the issue comes from pointer-events: none; in class .overlay-content . However, if I get rid of it, both links become unclickable.

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/y2auh7gn/

Comment: the problem is you have pointer-events:none

Comment: Yeah, the problem is definitely with `pointer-events: none`, in conjunction with your `z-indexes`. You have a link that is only visible when one element (`.amg-corner-button_wrap`) is hovered over. When you hover over this link, you're no longer hovering over `.amg-corner-button_wrap`. Therefor, the link immediately disappears. If you are hovering over `.amg-corner-button_wrap`, you can't click the link. I don't think what you're trying to do is actually **possible**, sadly. The bets you can have is a link that disappears very fast.

Comment: Thank you @ObsidianAge. I am sure I saw this thing working on a website one day. I have been working on it since a few days now and it would be really a shame if it's indeed not possible...

Comment: @ShadowFiend I know the problem comes from pointer-events: none . But as I said, if I get rid of it, both links become unclickable.